# How to show Show popup from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

Can we show a alert dialog from a thread,the scenario is, activity which thread creates finishes(now the app finishes),hoping thread continue its background process,at the end need to show a popup.

Comment: you can use aynctask also. With that showing popup won't be a big deal

Comment: You should not do that. Try changing your design.

Comment: If you want to show popups after application is finished, you may use `Service`. Because when you want to show UI views like popups, they must be displayed with `Context`, like `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: Or, if you mean "after thread is finished", not "app", I recommend that you use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: am doing calculation inside the thread, when it reaches to 0 i need to show popup,one more clarification, is thread finishes by OS by the unavailability of resource like memory. Service or thread which is best for showing popup from background.